# What is the font in this document?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

What is the font used in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~kronheim/khovanov-unknot.pdf?

Comment: You should know that most PDF viewers will show you want fonts are embedded in a document if you view the document properties. There's also the `pdffonts` command line tool which is part of [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

Comment: This is all very funny.  I was a grad student in Kronheimer's department and we students had several conversations about his font choices.

Answer (score 8):

The math font is [Math Time Pro 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). It's a commercial font, but you have a lite version available for free (it lacks bold versions of the characters and several companion alphabets).

If you prefer open source fonts, you can use `\usepackage{txfonts}` or `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (they are also based on Times, so will look similar, but not identical to Math Time).

Answer (score 3):

The free tool pdffonts, part of the [Xpdf package](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), lists these fonts:

```
#name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
YKGYYT+TimesNRMT-Italic              Type 1            yes yes no     223  0
CSSMXZ+TimesNRMT                     Type 1            yes yes no     224  0
KKTOEZ+TimesNRMT-Bold                Type 1            yes yes no     225  0
WXZSBU+MT2MIT                        Type 1            yes yes no     226  0
QMXOWD+MT2MIS                        Type 1            yes yes no     228  0
DJJNFC+MT2HRBT                       Type 1            yes yes no     229  0
JEXKNT+MT2SYT                        Type 1            yes yes no     230  0
FLRMQD+MT2EXE                        Type 1            yes yes no     278  0
EWHDMI+MT2MST                        Type 1            yes yes no     318  0
VHLUYE+MT2EXA                        Type 1            yes yes no     331  0
FXFJOL+MT2SYS                        Type 1            yes yes no     336  0
ROQMZM+MT2MIF                        Type 1            yes yes no     347  0
IQAFAX+MT2SYAT                       Type 1            yes yes no     360  0
FGEHNK+MT2MFT                        Type 1            yes yes no     366  0
SCTTVY+MT2SYF                        Type 1            yes yes no     380  0
FRCNYW+XYATIP10                      Type 1            yes yes no     381  0
QMCZUA+XYBTIP10                      Type 1            yes yes no     382  0
SASSGL+TimesNRSevenMT                Type 1            yes yes no     433  0
GPTPAD+MT2HRBS                       Type 1            yes yes no     473  0
LRVZRZ+TimesNRSevenMT-Bold           Type 1            yes yes no     520  0
NWYXFL+MT2MSS                        Type 1            yes yes no     561  0
EDSPEO+MT2MFS                        Type 1            yes yes no     609  0
MUFXUX+TimesNRExpertMT               Type 1            yes yes no     708  0
VNMCFP+MT2HRBDT                      Type 1            yes yes no     804  0
PWVYZY+MT2BMIT                       Type 1            yes yes no     805  0
QJZBHF+XYDASH10                      Type 1            yes yes no     855  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes    891  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes    968  0
BKUZYQ+CMSS10                        Type 1            yes yes no    1078  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1111  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1112  0
TXFAPN+MT2BMIS                       Type 1            yes yes no    1151  0
WQGJVV+CMSS8                         Type 1            yes yes no    1187  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1273  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1274  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1330  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1331  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1356  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1357  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1380  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1381  0
TimesNewRomanItalic                  CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1505  0
TimesNewRoman                        CID TrueType      yes no  yes   1506  0
```

Besides Times New Roman TrueType, there's the Monotype TimesNR Type 1 font. Have a look at [Monotype TimesNR font pack](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/mnt.txt) on CTAN.

Comment: The main difference between Monotype's version of the Times fonts and other clones is that they come with real small caps and have optical sizes. However, as far as I can see, the Seven optical size is only used in the very few exponents set in roman (e.g. `$I^{\mathrm{Floer}}$`, page 75) and the small caps are only used a few times (mainly between pages 50 and 60). For everything else concerning the text, there won't be any real difference between the Monotype version and the Nimbus Roman clone coming with LaTeX.